# Parsing large xml files

Tags: xml, sqlite, xml-parsing, simple-framework, android-json

Hiii. I need some help parsing this really big xml document. More specifically the bible.

Which would be the most efficient way of doing this? I've tried parsing it with standard xml tools but it takes too much time or simply crashes. I've also tried converting it into json but that didn't work out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIRC The version of the New Testament created by Jon Bosak is about 1Mb, and the Old Testament about 3Mb. That's not "really big". How big is "really big" in your case? Give us some numbers - you wouldn't ask us for help building a "really tall" building without giving us the height, would you?

Comment: And be more specific about the problem. What tools did you use, how did you run them, how long did they take, what did they say when they crashed?

Comment: It's about 5mb. About 50,000 lines. It takes too much time to read it

Comment: 5Mb is tiny by modern standards. How long is too long?

Comment: I used simpleXML and pullparser. Well. Parsing 50,000 lines is pretty memory consuming. Have you accomplished this before??? Please tell me how

Comment: App. Freezes. Out of memory

Comment: I don't know simpleXML but on a decent platform these days parsing 200Mb is no problem.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://rythie.com/blog/blog/2011/02/27/using-a-hybrid-of-xmlreader-and-simplexml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sqlite... much simpler to use